# How to fit a time series moving average in R?

Tags: r, mean, raster

I have a raster stack similar to the example and a period of 62 days. I want to fit a time series moving average with lenght equal to the 62 days period. How can I do this in R?

```
library(greenbrown)
data("ndvimap")

#here I have an issue as I do not know how to set the length and run the window
#filt<-focal(ndvimap, fun=mean, na.rm=T)#it does not work
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand if you want to summarize your stack every 62 layers or every 62 days. However, here is a possible solution for both cases:

```
library(greenbrown)
library(raster)
data("ndvimap")

#do the mean every 62 layers
step <- 62
nlayer <- nlayers(ndvimap)
sequence <-
  split(1:nlayer, rep(1:round(nlayer / step), c(
    rep(step, 5), nlayer - floor(nlayer / step) * step
  )))

res <- lapply(sequence,FUN = function(x){
  mean <- calc(ndvimap[[x]],mean)
})
res <- stack(res)

#do the mean every 2 layers (~62 days)
step <- 2
sequence <- split(1:nlayer,rep(1:(nlayer/step),each=step))

res <- lapply(sequence,FUN = function(x){
  mean <- calc(ndvimap[[x]],mean)
})
res <- stack(res)
```

Comment: Does this second example represent a 'moving window' approach? i.e. could it be used to average out rasters with daily values into 3 day averages so as to fill in NAs from a cloud mask for example? Would it take the average of the 'current' and two previous days in this case?

Comment: yes, it could be used to create a cloud-free composite for example. the number of rasters summarized depends on the step and the number of layers of the stack. in your example, if you want to calculate 3 day's average it will take the average of the 'current' and two previous days

Comment: Its a bit difficult to tell what is happening where there is an NA in a group of 3 values. Say for example we have 3, NA, 1 over 3 days at a given pixel. Would this return (3 + 1)/2 = 4 or (3 + 0 + 1)/3=1.25 or simply NA? Also is it possible to take the average of the previous, current and 1 day into the future?

Comment: it is not difficult at all. the behavior with NA values depends on the argument of `mean` in `calc`. If you set the `na.rm` argument to `TRUE` the NA values are dropped so in your example a pixel with values 3, NA, and 1 will be summarized to (3+1)/2=2, and if you set `na.rm` to `FALSE` it will return NA. Finally, yes it is possible to take the average of the previous, current, and future days because it all depends on the list of indices that you create with `split()`. If you can manipulate the indices fed to `calc` you can summarise which layers you want.